# Property access. Logic in getter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

`ObjectID` is my own ID-class

In my mapped Entity-class I have next getter for ID

```
   @Id
   @Column(name = "aa_id")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "PatientSequenceGenerator",
                      sequenceName = "patient_seq")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                   generator = "PatientSequenceGenerator")
   public ObjectID getId()
   {
      return id;
   }
```

generator generate Long value, so I got exception

```
this id generator generates long, integer, short or string
```

So, do I can add to my getter logic, that will create ObjectID from long, for example

```
//annotations
    public ObjectID getId()
           {  
//logic that that get Long from sequance
              return new ObjectID(gettedLong);
           }
```

Comment: If you need a custom ID class, you need a custom generator that gives that to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do that. Your ID field should be of one of the listed types or an `@EmbeddedId` or an `@IdClass`

Comment: Can I use generator for @EmbeddedId ?

Comment: I don't know. You can use for `String` for example. But do you really need it to be that complex?